# How can I install Debian on a PowerBook G3 with Mac OS 9.2?

Tags: startup, unix, classic-mac-os

Today I started installing Debian Linux on an old Macintosh PowerBook G3 with Mac OS 9.2. After a long time of backing up old documents I erased the whole disk. At the end I just want Debian installed, so I did that. Than I've burned a Debian CD (DVD won't work) and inserted it into the PowerBook. I wanted to boot from this CD with pressing <kbd>C</kbd> at boot, but I always just get a big question mark on the screen.
Please help me, because I already tried more than a hour with booting the disk and it never worked.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1440

Comment: Yes I now that this is because I deleted the original systeme, but how can I install the Linux from the disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this how to article](http://research.naumachiarius.com/ibook-debian.html):

You'll need a working OS X partition and you'll need to reboot with <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. It is a bit complicated so follow the link for more info.

I personally would go with Ubuntu on your Powerbook. Follow [this guide](http://linuxtidbits.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/reviving-a-power-mac-g4-with-ubuntu-server/) for info on how to install. Although the guide is for a Power Mac G4, it should work with your Powerbook.

Comment: @leo Ok, lemme know how it works out. Hope this helps you!

Comment: See also [open firmware](http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/ancient/whatismacosx/arch_boot.html)

Comment: Ok I tried it some times last week but I've given up, just for a short time. I'm sure I'll try it again in the next days, but currently I really haven't got the time for that :).

Comment: Ok, lemme know if you need any more help!